# Fuzzy Search + Inverted Indexing

Tags: search, text, indexing, fuzzy-search

I am studying fuzzy search and how to retrieve information from database using a Inverted Indexing. I studied Inverted Indexing and I think it only works for EXACT match. Imagine the situation I have the string `East Lamar Street` in my database. Someone is looking for `East Lmar Street` and I what to find `East Lamar Street`.

Will it use Edit Distance?

How the algorithm will operate?

Is the database going to use the inverted indexing?

Or it will do a full scan?

I saw that it uses a hash to make the operation in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small library that indexes using Soundex by word and scores using Levenshtein distance on the entire phrase. There is a scala and C# version. You could use this if you can afford loading loading all of your street names into memory. Otherwise you may to could take some of the source and use it differently.

https://github.com/rstokes/fuzzysearch